# Creating a computed column in a View. Is it possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, calculated-columns

My SQL view returns the following

```
ID Name
AA Gina
AB George
AC John
```

I would like to add a computed column `UpCounter` so my view returns something like

```
ID Name    UpCounter
AA Gina    1
AB George  2
AC John    3
```

Is it possible?

**UPDATE:** The UpCounter is actually the row index

Comment: Which sql server are you using .... View is basically a select which is evaluated at runtime (Not considering Indexed views). So Like select, you can do any calculation or call any ufd for column in view ...

Comment: The short answer is "yes", though methodology depends on which version of SQL you have. Also, what are the criteria for populating column UpCounter?

Comment: @Jamiec Actually yes. The Name of the third record is John

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [OVER Clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx).

```
SELECT ID, Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID ASC) AS UpCounter
FROM xyz
```

Here's a use case:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT 'AA' as ID, 'Gina' as Name
    UNION
    SELECT 'AB' as ID, 'George' as Name
    UNION
    SELECT 'AC' as ID, 'John' as Name
)
SELECT ID, Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID ASC) AS UpCounter
FROM x
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ROW_NUMBER() function:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [ID]) AS MyIndex, 
       [ID], 
       [Name] 
FROM   MyTable
```

Also, note that a computed column is something different. A computed column is a "virtual column" on a table that just stores the forumla to be calculated then the field is selected. It does not take up row space.